# How to get events from other classes?

Tags: c#, user-interface, event-handling

What is the best way to pass an event between classes.
The problem is: I have a connection Class, and when a specific USB device is connected I want the GUI (which will be configuring the device) which is another Class, to have a "connected" sign, and when its disconnected to have a "disconnected" sign.
I am thinking about creating a new eventHandler, and add an this eventHandler to the UI controller Class, and the connection Class will "fire" the event, is this correct, or is there a better way?

Comment: You need to create the event in the class that fires it. Add your code.

Comment: I dont have any code yet, I was just checking the best way to code it (שנה טובה ;) )

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways of approaching this. One is to have an [event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8627sbea%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that fires when the connection state changes. The GUI can listen to the event and update its display appropriately. This is a relatively simple model and is well supported across different libraries because events are part of the C# language.

The second way, using Windows Presentation Foundation or a similar library, is via [data binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750612.aspx). The UI controls "bind" to the connection class and, when the connection class's properties update, the UI updates automatically. This is slightly more complicated to set up and is library specific (the link is for WPF). However, it is a far more powerful and flexible concept.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try using the `EventAggregator` from Microsoft Prism. I prefer it because it's highly decoupled and fairly lightweight as well.

More on Prism and the `EventAggregator`:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122(v=pandp.20).aspx